# Why should we use try-catch while writing database connection?

Tags: java, try-catch, sqlexception

while using the code for connecting to the database it asks for surrounding it inside a try catch block.

Connection

```
mycs=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest [root on Default schema]");
```

Comment: When you're designing a program that connects to a database, you need to think about what the program should do if something goes wrong in the database, for example, the connection fails.  Once you've made a decision about what should happen - the `catch` block is the place for the code to run when things fail.

Answer (score 2):

B/c the driver is trying to establish connection, and if it fails (for tons of possible reasons), exception is thrown. For example, MySQL server is not running, javatest doesn't exist...

Notice that `try-catch` in not the only way for dealing with exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

`DriverManager.getConnection` throws **[`SQLException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlexception.html)**, which is checked exception and that needs to be handled or thrown.

Also, it is always a good practice to handle or propagate the exception correctly. This is not only limited to database connection instead elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the declaration of the method you will see it is declared as:

```
    public static Connection getConnection(String url)
        throws SQLException {
        ...
    }
```

SQLException is a checked exception, means when you call a method that throws a checked Exception, you must handle it by try-catch, or you propagate it by declare the caller method with this exception too.

So there must be something called unchecked exception, right? Yes and they include all subclasses of RuntimeException.

When a method throws a checked exception, it wants the caller to know there is a chance that something would go wrong, and you cannot ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, any checked exception needs to be either **handled** (option 1) or to be **specified** (option 2) in the method signature (look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) on **Catch or Specify Requirement**).

Now, specific to, `DriverManager`'s `getConnection` method, it throws a checked exception (i.e., `SQLException`) and you can look for the API below (or [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-)). So you can handle it using try-catch block or specify it (using `throws` cluase in the method signature).

> public static Connection getConnection(String url)
>                                   throws SQLException
>
> Attempts to establish a connection to the given database URL. The
>   DriverManager attempts to select an appropriate driver from the set of
>   registered JDBC drivers.
>
> Returns:
>       a connection to the URL
>
> **Throws**:
>       **SQLException** - **if a database access error occurs or the url is null**

**Note:** If you choose option(2) (i.e., specifying it), then the caller of your method needs to take care of it (i.e., again handle it or specify it)